# reload vue component from outside

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a laravel vue project that displays a list of items in a component. The component when mounted makes an ajax call to populate the data element. However, there's other items on the page (not in vue) that can add elements to the database, and I'd like to make sure the list is reactive in the component.

```
mounted() {
    this.getTasks();
},
methods: {
    getTasks() {
        let self = this;
        axios.get('/tasks').then(response => {
            self.tasks = response.data;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    },
}
```

When the user does an action that would add a task to the list, is there a way to fire the `getTasks` method on the component from outside the component?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a global function (binding context to Vue component) when component is mounted:

```
mounted() {
  windows.getTasks = this.getTasks.bind(this);
  this.getTasks();
},
```

Then you can use it outside calling `getTasks()` or `windows.getTasks()`

Answer (score 0):

You should use vuex actions.

Here's an example:

```
Vue.component('ChildB',{
  template:`
    <div class="child childB">
      <h1> Score: {{ score }} </h1>
      <button @click="changeScore">Change Score</button>
    </div>`,
  computed: {
    score () {
      return this.$store.getters.score
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeScore () {
      this.$store.dispatch('incrementScore', 3000)
    }
  }
})
```

full source:

https://codepen.io/tutsplus/pen/MXpPLz

Comment: i would try to avoid at all costs global functions. you can use vuex to manage the state and then you can call that same method on the component. that way you can control the state- the above example is a good example of a methods that fires an action with payload. if you want lets say fire 2 methods on the same time just use computed. getters are also a great way to get specific data. i hope i could help